# centos 7 laravel log - everyday new log file instorage gets created owned by root need apache to be owner of log file

Tags: laravel, apache, centos, centos7

I have this strange issue on Cent os 7, where i have installed laravel .

I have installed apache  httpd server and granted access  to the laravel Logs directory .

Everything works fine   if  I set the owner of the log files to  apache.

So what happens is laravel creates  a new log file daily in the storage folder and when it does all of a sudden the owner of that new log file for example  laravel-2020-05-22.log  is no longer apache but  root.

So thats my issue , I have  to everyday go to the log file and change its owner from root to apache  for it to work.

```
sudo chown -R apache:apache /var/www/html/laravel/storage/logs
```

I have already executed the command to make apache the owner of the logs directory recursively.

How do i make the new logs that are being created daily be automatically owned by apache and not root ?

Comment: are you using log rotation to create daily Apache httd logging?

Comment: no  this is different .. its laravel a php based framework .. that writes log files daily to a folder mentioned above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest hassle free way to solve it was to stop logs from being written into the storage folder  and just save  it into a logging database instead.